# Blank result from ListContourPlot[]

Tags: plotting

I was trying to make a `ListContourPlot` of some data. I have triplets of data of the form `{x, y, f[x, y]}`. A part of this data is the following:

```
table={{0.2, -7.*10^-9, 0.987445}, {0.2, -6.8*10^-9, 
0.987161}, {0.2, -6.6*10^-9, 0.986873}, {0.2, -6.4*10^-9, 
0.986583}, {0.2, -6.2*10^-9, 0.986289}, {0.2, -6.*10^-9, 
0.985992}, {0.2, -5.8*10^-9, 0.985692}, {0.2, -5.6*10^-9, 
0.985389}, {0.2, -5.4*10^-9, 0.985083}, {0.2, -5.2*10^-9, 
0.984773}, {0.2, -5.*10^-9, 0.984461}, {0.2, -4.8*10^-9, 
0.984145}, {0.2, -4.6*10^-9, 0.983827}, {0.2, -4.4*10^-9, 
0.983505}, {0.2, -4.2*10^-9, 0.98318}, {0.2, -4.*10^-9, 
0.982852}, {0.2, -3.8*10^-9, 0.982521}, {0.2, -3.6*10^-9, 
0.982187}, {0.2, -3.4*10^-9, 0.98185}, {0.2, -3.2*10^-9, 
0.98151}, {0.2, -3.*10^-9, 0.981167}, {0.2, -2.8*10^-9, 
0.980821}, {0.2, -2.6*10^-9, 0.980471}, {0.2, -2.4*10^-9, 
0.980119}, {0.2, -2.2*10^-9, 0.979763}, {0.2, -2.*10^-9, 
0.979405}, {0.3, -7.*10^-9, 0.991915}, {0.3, -6.8*10^-9, 
0.991569}, {0.3, -6.6*10^-9, 0.991217}, {0.3, -6.4*10^-9, 
0.990858}, {0.3, -6.2*10^-9, 0.990491}, {0.3, -6.*10^-9, 
0.990117}, {0.3, -5.8*10^-9, 0.989737}, {0.3, -5.6*10^-9, 
0.989349}, {0.3, -5.4*10^-9, 0.988954}, {0.3, -5.2*10^-9, 
0.988552}, {0.3, -5.*10^-9, 0.988143}, {0.3, -4.8*10^-9, 
0.987727}, {0.3, -4.6*10^-9, 0.987303}, {0.3, -4.4*10^-9, 
0.986873}, {0.3, -4.2*10^-9, 0.986436}, {0.3, -4.*10^-9, 
0.985992}, {0.3, -3.8*10^-9, 0.985541}, {0.3, -3.6*10^-9, 
0.985083}, {0.3, -3.4*10^-9, 0.984617}, {0.3, -3.2*10^-9, 
0.984145}, {0.3, -3.*10^-9, 0.983666}, {0.3, -2.8*10^-9, 
0.98318}, {0.3, -2.6*10^-9, 0.982687}, {0.3, -2.4*10^-9, 
0.982187}, {0.3, -2.2*10^-9, 0.981681}, {0.3, -2.*10^-9, 
0.981167}, {0.4, -7.*10^-9, 0.995414}, {0.4, -6.8*10^-9, 
0.995063}, {0.4, -6.6*10^-9, 0.9947}, {0.4, -6.4*10^-9, 
0.994324}, {0.4, -6.2*10^-9, 0.993935}, {0.4, -6.*10^-9, 
0.993534}, {0.4, -5.8*10^-9, 0.99312}, {0.4, -5.6*10^-9, 
0.992692}, {0.4, -5.4*10^-9, 0.992253}, {0.4, -5.2*10^-9, 
0.9918}, {0.4, -5.*10^-9, 0.991335}, {0.4, -4.8*10^-9, 
0.990858}, {0.4, -4.6*10^-9, 0.990367}, {0.4, -4.4*10^-9, 
0.989864}, {0.4, -4.2*10^-9, 0.989349}, {0.4, -4.*10^-9, 
0.988821}, {0.4, -3.8*10^-9, 0.98828}, {0.4, -3.6*10^-9, 
0.987727}, {0.4, -3.4*10^-9, 0.987161}, {0.4, -3.2*10^-9, 
0.986583}, {0.4, -3.*10^-9, 0.985992}, {0.4, -2.8*10^-9, 
0.985389}, {0.4, -2.6*10^-9, 0.984773}, {0.4, -2.4*10^-9, 
0.984145}, {0.4, -2.2*10^-9, 0.983505}, {0.4, -2.*10^-9, 
0.982852}, {0.5, -7.*10^-9, 0.997932}, {0.5, -6.8*10^-9, 
0.997633}, {0.5, -6.6*10^-9, 0.997313}, {0.5, -6.4*10^-9, 
0.996974}, {0.5, -6.2*10^-9, 0.996614}}

ListContourPlot[table, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

But I get a totally blank area, absolutely nothing. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

The second coordinate is tiny! Try scaling it to order 1:

```
scaledYTable = table /. {x_, y_, f_} :> {x, 10^9 y, f};
ListContourPlot[
  scaledYTable
  , PlotLegends -> Automatic
  , PlotRange -> Automatic
]
```

[image: Working ListContourPlot]

Comment: You  can also use the option `ScalingFunctions -> {None, {10^9 # &, 10^-9 # &}, None}` (+1)

Comment: @kglr That's a much better method than mine! (because it scales the second coordinate without having to touch the data.) Could you turn it into an answer?

Comment: thank you! I'm analyzing other data, I will try this when it will stop running!

Comment: If I put ScalingFunctions in ListContourPlot it gives me a red word